# UPDATE Many to One Relationship in REST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, one-to-many, many-to-one

I need ideas to solve my problem. I have a one-to-many relationship between user and company. There is no problem with data transfer between client and server. The problem is when I send the company object, user is set to null automatically while sending the data

UPDATE: When I fetched User object, I also get the related companies. The problem is when I fetched the Company object, i get the user field as null !

EDIT: User field sent filled from client but server gets the user as null. I couldnt find the problem.

Here is my code snippet.

```
@Entity(name="user")
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable {
..
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference("company")
    private List<Company> userCompanies = new ArrayList<Company>(0);
..
}

@Entity(name="company")
@Table(name="company")
public class Company {
..
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference("company")
    private User user;
..
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/company/update", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody void updateCompany(@RequestBody Company company) {
    companyService.updateCompany(company);
}
```

Comment: I did not understand why you need to set user to null? `JsonBackReference` annotation is used for solving this problem, you should not need to set user to null.

Comment: I don't set it to null. It automatically does that when sends the data. I am trying to understand why that happens?

Comment: Actually there's a better way to handle bi-directional relationships in Jackson 2. Use `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")` on both your User and Company classes, and change property to whatever field you're using as the id of those classes.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Could it be related to somewhere different?

Comment: I have no idea then, you need to debug and see why your user object is null. Make sure that client sends the user field filled.

Comment: It is filled on client side but server gets it null.. So problem might be in my annotations or i dont know..